# Is it tractable to have Rails models not subclass ActiveRecord or ActiveModel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't like the idea that in Rails models are used both for business logic and persistance.  I'd love to separate the two: have my models contain business logic, and use another class hierarchy to persist.

Has anyone tried this and gotten any traction?  Off the top of my head it seems like it goes too strongly against Rails:  form_for requires an ActiveModel object to work, as do many common plugins that work directly on business objects.

Any thoughts?

Comment: As a general rule, going against the philosophy of Rails is not something I'd recommend. You could end up doing a lot of monkey patches. That may work. Until you want to update Rails. And everything blows up ...

Comment: The business logic itself can be separated into a module that you mixin to the model. The model itself being used in the form_for makes sense as part of the persistence. There's a fair amount of info out there on the presenter pattern.

Comment: There's been a lot of this going around recently. You might be interested in http://objectsonrails.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's going to be hard/annoying to do it exactly as you state, but there are some good ways to separate out your code.

One way to do it would be to, just as you said, have 2 separate classes, one for persistence and one for business logic. Let's call them Foo and FooBL. Foo would inherit from ActiveRecord, contain validation logic, and some simple methods for querying and manipulating the data.  FooBL would be a regular ruby class that would use the Foo class as needed. You could even use some of Ruby's [Delegation](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/) features so some of the attributes and methods of Foo could be used directly.

Another slightly different way is to use Presenters, like in the [Draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper) gem. Rather than breaking off the business logic from the the persistence logic, it breaks off the view-related logic. Not exactly what you're looking for, but it still helps in cleaning up your code.

I would also recommend that you take a look at Avdi Grimm's book, [Object on Rails](http://objectsonrails.com). He takes a deep look at some of these patterns and practices.

Good luck!